# clone a github project with specific tag using .sh (shell)

Tags: git, shell, github

I tried with no success clone a github project with specific tag  using shell .sh

In that case I want download this version: https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/releases/tag/v0.8.0

the fun part is the litecoin path does not exist and if just use: `git clone -b 0.8 https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin.git`

I can clone the project.

I using this lines in my .sh

```
git clone https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin.git
git tag -l
git checkout 0.8

# git clone --branch 0.8 git@github.com:litecoin-project/litecoin.git
# git clone -b 0.8 https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin.git
```

error I don't have the litecoin folder in my pc but keeps me showing this:

```
fatal: destination path 'litecoin' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error

```
fatal: destination path 'litecoin' already exists and is not an empty directory
```

happens if you try cloning without removing the folder that exists already

The errors

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

are because you need to cd into litecoin folder first.

```
git clone https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin
cd litecoin
git tag -l
git checkout 0.8
```

works fine for me

Comment: thank you for your help but using the shell script does not show me the folder I cloned but says exist, not using the shell show me the folder, so weird, what do u think can be?

Comment: what happens if you run rm -r litecoin before running the script?

Comment: does not give the option to delete the folder, the folder does not exist, :(, the folder just appears if I do clone out of the shell script

Comment: what happens if you chmod 777 script.sh? it sounds like a permissions issue possibly

Comment: I have already did this, whitout the permission the script does not run, can you see the folder after run the script?

Comment: Yes works perfectly here :( is it possibly you have the script saved on a fat32 partition or something similar? maybe try relocating the script to home if it's not there already as a test...

Comment: I found the issue,  does not matter where I run the command the litecoin directory goes to my home folder, why? can make it install in the folder I am running the script?  thank you

Comment: Ahh I see, usually it uses current directory as default...try adding in a path after the clone command eg. git clone https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin ~/Desktop/litecoin2 for example

Comment: now moves to desktop, but appears this: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Are you "cd"ing into the folder before running the last 2 git commands?